# google Apps script XML Parsing Issues from a feed

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I have a feed which has a username and password and I need to parse it to a Google sheet.

Here is the code I currently have which the company have provided:

```
function populateSheetWithCSV(sheet, csvUrl, user, pw) {
 var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl, {
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(
     user + ':' + pw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)
   }
});
 var doc = XmlService.parse(resp);
 var students = doc.getRootElement().getAllContent();
 var spreadsheetContent = [];
 var maxLength = 0;
 for (var j=0; j<students.length-1; j++)
 {
  var length = students[j].getValue().trim().split('\n').length;
  if (maxLength < length)
  {
    maxLength = length;
  }
 }
 for (var i=0; i<students.length-1; i++)
 {
   var studentDetails = students[i].getValue().trim().split('\n');
   if (studentDetails.length > 1) {
studentDetails=studentDetails.map(s => s.trim()); 
     if (studentDetails.length < maxLength)
     {
       var diff = maxLength - studentDetails.length;
       for (var k = 0; k<diff; k++)
       {
         studentDetails.unshift('');
       }
     }
     spreadsheetContent.push(studentDetails);
   }
 }
 Logger.log(spreadsheetContent);
   sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
   sheet.getRange(
       1, 1,
       spreadsheetContent.length /* rows */,
       maxLength /* columns */).setValues(spreadsheetContent);
}
function main()
{
 populateSheetWithCSV(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
                    'REPORT LIVE DATA FEED URL',
                    'SCHOOLID',
                   'YOUR KEY HERE');
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <LegalFullName>test user</LegalFullName>
    <Granted_x0020_Date />
    <CombinedParentalConsentList />
    <StudentTutorGroup />
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <LegalFullName>joe bloggs</LegalFullName>
    <Granted_x0020_Date />
    <CombinedParentalConsentList />
    <StudentTutorGroup>12G</StudentTutorGroup>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I have modified the code a little bit but the issue is that the xml table is formatted is a way that I cant pull the elements and name them.

```
var values = [
  [ "LegalFullName" , "Date"    , "Consent" , "Tutor" ]
];
sheet.insertRows(1, 1);
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,4);
Logger.log = range
range.setValues(values);
```

The issue is this is just an example and the data contained can be different but while parsing it doesn't read the elements and so sometimes if there is no data the data changes columns.

I am hoping it to parse it as a normal xml but as its a feed and we have no control on how the feed is given headers of columns are not there and so I have had to modify the script slightly with this.

But as I don't always know the value of the feed id can become hard and so have to curl it. And another issue is there is no id on the element. I have tried multiple variations of the code including using other version types but as there is no ID on the element it makes it really hard. The xml is just an example typically there will be over 2000 records.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike when I pull the webfeed via curl i get xml as shown but when parsing using the script i get no headings and as much as I have tried I cannot seem to pull the heading as the xml elements have no ID  as you can see. and all I want to do is put this into a google spreadsheet.